# Summing XML data that is in two arrays

Tags: xml, arrays, xslt, xpath, addition

I am very new to XSL and XML and have, I hope, an easy question.  I have an XML file that has two arrays of numbers in them that I need to sum.  Here is part of the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<out_xml>
<Root>
    <ItemCollection>
        <Item name="BaseLineOffSet" type="2">
            <Histogram>
                <DispOrder>This is Order</DispOrder>
                <IntensityArray>
                    <Intensity>105.84667205810547</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>105.83854675292969</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>105.57729339599609</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>105.66104888916016</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>105.56392669677734</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>105.33917236328125</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>105.33854675292969</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>105.31544494628906</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>105.40036010742187</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>105.21470642089844</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>105.14356994628906</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>104.92792510986328</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>104.93791961669922</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>104.93979644775391</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>104.96470642089844</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>105.01107025146484</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>104.76479339599609</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>104.9085693359375</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>104.70166778564453</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>104.75499725341797</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>104.77352905273437</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>104.77714538574219</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>104.59485626220703</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>104.73235321044922</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>104.35479736328125</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>104.56911468505859</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>104.38999938964844</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>104.30992889404297</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>104.37964630126953</Intensity>
                </IntensityArray>
            </Histogram>
        </Item>
        <Item name="DispIntervalsMaxValues" type="2">
            <Histogram>
                <DispOrder>This is Order</DispOrder>
                <IntensityArray>
                    <Intensity>1.0229243040084839</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>48.868541717529297</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>47.504795074462891</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>162.17105102539062</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>91.323570251464844</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>44.405426025390625</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>51.243541717529297</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>131.44705200195312</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>2.8496425151824951</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>21.435295104980469</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>47.006423950195312</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>0.72917240858078003</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>46.669178009033203</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>83.804801940917969</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>44.197799682617187</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>32.138923645019531</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>30.30479621887207</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>58.928920745849609</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>29.930421829223633</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>38.282505035400391</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>30.801467895507813</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>43.710361480712891</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>38.167644500732422</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>27.842643737792969</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>34.102294921875</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>61.118381500244141</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>10.910002708435059</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>3.6150767803192139</Intensity>
                    <Intensity>3.1703603267669678</Intensity>
                </IntensityArray>
            </Histogram>
        </Item>
    </ItemCollection>
</Root>
</out_xml>
```

What I really want is the sum of the the elements from the two Intensity arrays to be added up.  So it would be something like this:

FirstArray[0]+SecondArray[0]=sum[0] which is really

105.84667205810547 + 1.0229243040084839=106.8696
and

FirstArray[1]+SecondArray[1] =sum[1]

105.83854675292969+ 48.868541717529297=154.7071 and so on ...

There are a few other Items in between these two that I need to ignore for now.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**:

Look at `sum` function, e.g.:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k" match="Intensity" use="count(preceding-sibling::Intensity)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//Intensity[generate-id(.) = 
                           generate-id(key('k', count(preceding-sibling::Intensity)))]"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Intensity">
    <sum>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('k', count(preceding-sibling::Intensity)))"/>
    </sum>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This template sums `Intensity` elements for both `IntensityArray`.

Output:

```
<root>
  <sum>106.86959636211395</sum>
  <sum>154.70708847045898</sum>
  <sum>153.08208847045898</sum>
  <sum>267.8320999145508</sum>
  <sum>196.8874969482422</sum>
  <sum>149.74459838867187</sum>
  <sum>156.58208847045898</sum>
  <sum>236.7624969482422</sum>
  <sum>108.25000262260437</sum>
  <sum>126.6500015258789</sum>
  <sum>152.14999389648437</sum>
  <sum>105.65709751844406</sum>
  <sum>151.60709762573242</sum>
  <sum>188.74459838867187</sum>
  <sum>149.16250610351562</sum>
  <sum>137.14999389648437</sum>
  <sum>135.06958961486816</sum>
  <sum>163.8374900817871</sum>
  <sum>134.63208961486816</sum>
  <sum>143.03750228881836</sum>
  <sum>135.5749969482422</sum>
  <sum>148.48750686645508</sum>
  <sum>142.76250076293945</sum>
  <sum>132.5749969482422</sum>
  <sum>138.45709228515625</sum>
  <sum>165.68749618530273</sum>
  <sum>115.3000020980835</sum>
  <sum>107.92500567436218</sum>
  <sum>107.5500066280365</sum>
</root>
```

Comment: Hi Kirill - I guess I was not clear.  I need the sum of each element, not the whole array. So 105.8466721+1.022924304 then 105.8385468+48.86854172 etc...

Comment: Hi Kirill, this works but my true XML document is a quite a bit more complicated.  There were several runs that produce pairs of arrays that I need to sum.  Can all this get nested within a for-each loop ?

Comment: My previous comment got garbled...Hi Kirill, this works but my true XML document is a quite a bit more complicated.  For instance, within each run, there are several arrays named Intensity (such as Item name="BaseLineOffSet" -which I want and Item name="CompensatedData" which I do not want) so I need to select just Item name="BaseLineOffSet" and name="DispIntervalsMaxValues")  plus there were several runs that produce pairs of arrays that I need to sum (these are all higher in the tree than the <out_xml> node that I showed in the example.  Can all this get nested within a for-each loop ?

Comment: @user918967, Well, you can modify `<xsl:key>` definition, e.g.: `<xsl:key name="k" match="//Item[@name = 'BaseLineOffSet' or @name = 'DispIntervalsMaxValues']
            //Intensity" use="count(preceding-sibling::Intensity)"/>`

Answer (score 2):

Does the following do what you need it to?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//ItemCollection"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ItemCollection">
    <xsl:variable name="itemCollection" select="." />
    <xsl:variable name="itemsCount" select="count((.//IntensityArray)[1]//Intensity)" />

    <xsl:for-each select="1 to $itemsCount">
       <xsl:variable name="itemIndex" select="." />
       <sum position="{$itemIndex}">
         <xsl:value-of select="sum($itemCollection//IntensityArray//Intensity[$itemIndex])" />
       </sum>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I got the following output when I ran it on your sample data:

```
<root>
   <sum position="1">106.86959636211395</sum>
   <sum position="2">154.70708847045898</sum>
   <sum position="3">153.08208847045898</sum>
   <sum position="4">267.8320999145508</sum>
   <sum position="5">196.8874969482422</sum>
   <sum position="6">149.74459838867187</sum>
   <sum position="7">156.58208847045898</sum>
   <sum position="8">236.7624969482422</sum>
   <sum position="9">108.25000262260437</sum>
   <sum position="10">126.6500015258789</sum>
   <sum position="11">152.14999389648437</sum>
   <sum position="12">105.65709751844406</sum>
   <sum position="13">151.60709762573242</sum>
   <sum position="14">188.74459838867187</sum>
   <sum position="15">149.16250610351562</sum>
   <sum position="16">137.14999389648437</sum>
   <sum position="17">135.06958961486816</sum>
   <sum position="18">163.8374900817871</sum>
   <sum position="19">134.63208961486816</sum>
   <sum position="20">143.03750228881836</sum>
   <sum position="21">135.5749969482422</sum>
   <sum position="22">148.48750686645508</sum>
   <sum position="23">142.76250076293945</sum>
   <sum position="24">132.5749969482422</sum>
   <sum position="25">138.45709228515625</sum>
   <sum position="26">165.68749618530273</sum>
   <sum position="27">115.3000020980835</sum>
   <sum position="28">107.92500567436218</sum>
   <sum position="29">107.5500066280365</sum>
</root>
```

Comment: Hi Luke,  Running your code in EditX 2010 I got the following Error in expression 1 to $itemsCount: Unexpected token <name> beyond end of expression

Comment: Odd, it works fine for me in Saxon.  Since EditiX 2010 apparently supports XPath 2.0, does it help if you change the `version` attribute of the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element to `2.0`?

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation produces the wanted result even in cays the two node-sets have different number of nodes and/or some of the nodes in the 2nd node-set don't have value that is castable to a number**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vArr1" select=
   "/*/*/*/Item[1]/*/IntensityArray/*"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vArr2" select=
   "/*/*/*/Item[2]/*/IntensityArray/*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vShorterArr" select=
  "$vArr1[not(count($vArr1) > count($vArr2))]
  |
   $vArr2[not(count($vArr2) >= count($vArr1))]
  "/>

 <xsl:variable name="vLongerArr" select=
  "$vArr2[not(count($vArr1) > count($vArr2))]
  |
   $vArr1[not(count($vArr2) >= count($vArr1))]
  "/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <summedIntensities>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="$vLongerArr"/>
     </summedIntensities>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Intensity">
  <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
  <Intensity>
   <xsl:variable name="vVal2" select="$vShorterArr[position()=$vPos]"/>
   <xsl:value-of select=
     ".
   +
      concat('0',
             substring($vVal2,
                       1 div (number($vVal2) = number($vVal2))
                       )
             )
     "/>
  </Intensity>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the following XML document** (the same as the provided one, but added to the first node-set one more `Intensity` element (the last one), to make the two node-sets different in size):

```
<out_xml>
    <Root>
        <ItemCollection>
            <Item name="BaseLineOffSet" type="2">
                <Histogram>
                    <DispOrder>This is Order</DispOrder>
                    <IntensityArray>
                        <Intensity>105.84667205810547</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>105.83854675292969</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>105.57729339599609</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>105.66104888916016</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>105.56392669677734</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>105.33917236328125</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>105.33854675292969</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>105.31544494628906</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>105.40036010742187</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>105.21470642089844</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>105.14356994628906</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>104.92792510986328</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>104.93791961669922</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>104.93979644775391</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>104.96470642089844</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>105.01107025146484</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>104.76479339599609</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>104.9085693359375</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>104.70166778564453</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>104.75499725341797</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>104.77352905273437</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>104.77714538574219</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>104.59485626220703</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>104.73235321044922</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>104.35479736328125</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>104.56911468505859</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>104.38999938964844</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>104.30992889404297</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>104.37964630126953</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>105.37964630126953</Intensity>
                    </IntensityArray>
                </Histogram>
            </Item>
            <Item name="DispIntervalsMaxValues" type="2">
                <Histogram>
                    <DispOrder>This is Order</DispOrder>
                    <IntensityArray>
                        <Intensity>1.0229243040084839</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>48.868541717529297</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>47.504795074462891</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>162.17105102539062</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>91.323570251464844</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>44.405426025390625</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>51.243541717529297</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>131.44705200195312</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>2.8496425151824951</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>21.435295104980469</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>47.006423950195312</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>0.72917240858078003</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>46.669178009033203</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>83.804801940917969</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>44.197799682617187</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>32.138923645019531</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>30.30479621887207</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>58.928920745849609</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>29.930421829223633</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>38.282505035400391</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>30.801467895507813</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>43.710361480712891</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>38.167644500732422</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>27.842643737792969</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>34.102294921875</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>61.118381500244141</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>10.910002708435059</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>3.6150767803192139</Intensity>
                        <Intensity>3.1703603267669678</Intensity>
                    </IntensityArray>
                </Histogram>
            </Item>
        </ItemCollection>
    </Root>
</out_xml>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<summedIntensisites>
   <Intensity>106.86959636211395</Intensity>
   <Intensity>154.70708847045898</Intensity>
   <Intensity>153.08208847045898</Intensity>
   <Intensity>267.8320999145508</Intensity>
   <Intensity>196.8874969482422</Intensity>
   <Intensity>149.74459838867188</Intensity>
   <Intensity>156.58208847045898</Intensity>
   <Intensity>236.7624969482422</Intensity>
   <Intensity>108.25000262260437</Intensity>
   <Intensity>126.6500015258789</Intensity>
   <Intensity>152.14999389648438</Intensity>
   <Intensity>105.65709751844406</Intensity>
   <Intensity>151.60709762573242</Intensity>
   <Intensity>188.74459838867188</Intensity>
   <Intensity>149.16250610351562</Intensity>
   <Intensity>137.14999389648438</Intensity>
   <Intensity>135.06958961486816</Intensity>
   <Intensity>163.8374900817871</Intensity>
   <Intensity>134.63208961486816</Intensity>
   <Intensity>143.03750228881836</Intensity>
   <Intensity>135.5749969482422</Intensity>
   <Intensity>148.48750686645508</Intensity>
   <Intensity>142.76250076293945</Intensity>
   <Intensity>132.5749969482422</Intensity>
   <Intensity>138.45709228515625</Intensity>
   <Intensity>165.68749618530273</Intensity>
   <Intensity>115.3000020980835</Intensity>
   <Intensity>107.92500567436218</Intensity>
   <Intensity>107.5500066280365</Intensity>
   <Intensity>105.37964630126953</Intensity>
</summedIntensisites>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Two variables are defined, each containing the nodes that comprize an "array".
2. Another two variables are defined: `$vShorterArr`, containing the shorter node-set and `$vLongerArr` containing the longer node-set.
3. Templates are applied to the *longer* node-set.
4. Each node in the longer node-set is summed with the corresponding (if such exists) node in the shorter node-set, or with 0, otherwise.

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vArr1" select=
   "/*/*/*/Item[1]/*/IntensityArray/*/number()"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vArr2" select=
   "/*/*/*/Item[2]/*/IntensityArray/*/number()"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vShorterArr" select=
  "if(count($vArr1) lt count($vArr2))
     then $vArr1
     else $vArr2
  "/>
 <xsl:variable name="vLongerArr" select=
  "if(count($vArr1) ge count($vArr2))
     then $vArr1
     else $vArr2
  "/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <summedIntensities>
       <xsl:for-each select="$vLongerArr">
          <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
          <Intensity>
           <xsl:variable name="vVal2" select=
                "$vShorterArr[$vPos]"/>
           <xsl:sequence select=
             ".
           +
              (if($vVal2 castable as xs:double)
                then $vVal2
                else 0
                )
             "/>
          </Intensity>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </summedIntensities>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**III. Using FXSL**:

It is much easier to solve this problem using the **[`f:zip-with()`](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-zipWith.xsl?revision=1.3&view=markup)** function/template of **[FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)**.

**Below is a solution using FXSL 2**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 exclude-result-prefixes="f"
>
  <xsl:import href="../f/func-zipWithDVC.xsl"/>
  <xsl:import href="../f/func-Operators.xsl"/>

  <!-- To be applied on numList.xml -->
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <summedIntensities>
      <xsl:for-each select=
      "f:zipWith(f:add(),
                 /*/*/*/Item[1]/*/IntensityArray/*/number(),
                 /*/*/*/Item[2]/*/IntensityArray/*/number()
                 )"
      >
       <Intensity>
        <xsl:sequence select="."/>
       </Intensity>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </summedIntensities>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: My true XML document is a quite a bit more complicated.  There were several runs that produce pairs of arrays that I need to sum.  Can all this get nested within a for-each loop ?

Comment: @user918967: There is no need for `xsl:for-each` just impelemt your function `zip-with()`, or use the one provided by FXSL.

Comment: I was looking at the code again and Dimitre I think yours is easier to use when I am looking for a pair of Intensity arrays called Item name="BaseLineOffSet" and Item name="DispIntervalsMaxValues" and ignoring all the of Intensity arrays ...  Dmimitre, how would I alter the variables to only get those two arrays ?

Comment: @user918967: Define the two variables so that each selects the wanted element. If you need help with the XPath expression to specify, you need to provide the exact XML document and identify the exact two elements that must be selected.